# How to go into mobile app with gmail template linking

Tags: ios, swift, gmail, deep-linking

Hi in my project we are using Deep-linking.

when the user tap on email template user needs to go to concern page in mobile app.

by using of template I getting link like this: 
TaptoSchedule://host/inner

But backend people are giving link like : https://www.laundry.com/new-schedule/

How to we getting this type of functionalities in iOS please share any idea with me.

I follow this: http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/deep-linking-using-custom-url-scheme/

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

        if defaultValues.value(forKey: accessToken) != nil{

            let urlPath : String = url.path as String
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            //TaptoSchedule://host/inner

            if(urlPath == "/inner"){

                let innerPage: PickupController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PickupController") as! PickupController
                innerPage.selectedfrom = "Deeplink"
                self.window?.rootViewController = innerPage

            } else if (urlPath == "/about"){

            }
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            return true
        }else{
            setRootControllerBeforeLogin()
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your App's Associated domains you need to add "www.laundry.com". It will work fine after that. For Doing this go to your App Target->Capabilities->Associated Domains-> Add your web URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to talk to backend people to call

TaptoSchedule://host/inner

after user visit https://www.laundry.com/new-schedule/ in order to open your app

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to **use Universal Links instead of Deep Links**. Universal Links use the standard URL format which appears to be what your backend team is providing for you.

From a customer perspective the experience is essentially the same between Deep Links and Universal Links.  However, Universal Links give you some additional flexibility.  For example, Universal Links use the standard URL format, which can link to a webpage in cases where your user does not have your application installed.

**Check out the Apple documentation here for details:**
https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links